# DrpZone.js me sale server responded with 0 code y ya modifique apache

Tags: php, mysqli

Saludos amigos estoy usando dropzone.js pero al momento de subir archivos me sale un error el cual dice por favor ayuda ya modifique muchas cosas y nada

> server responded with 0 code

Y ya he modificado las opciones de php

[image: ya modifique]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Prodrias poner el código de tu servidor?

Answer (score 0):

En [GitHub](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/issues/701) se indica como un bug que puede ocurrir en Safari

Revisaste cambiar la URL de subida local por la del servidor, y sus permisos?

Comment: La pregunta fue hace casi un año, por lo que es muy probable que el OP no recuerde qué pasó con detalle. Si das una respuesta tardia, procura que sea para solucionar o, en última instancia, ayudar a solucionar el problema para que sirva para futuros visitantes.